# How to authenticate users to access WebAPI using ADFS SAML token

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, saml, adfs

I'm working on project having two applications (ASP.NET MVC) WebApp and WebAPI.
WebApp using ADFS for authentication, so user enters UserName and Password to login to WebAPP which goes to ADFS and ADFS returns SAML token to WebApp on successful authentication. My WebApp accessing some WebAPI's internally (WebAPI's are not secure for now).

Now I have ADFS SAML token in WebApp and I want to use same SAML token to access my WebAPI's.
How to implement this type of authentication in WebAPI application?

Comment: Are you using Azure AD at all or is this purely ADFS?

Comment: @Saca I'm using Azure AD